# Crashing web browser with more than 10 AudioContexts

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have a long play list of audio files and I need to visualize them with waveform like soundcloud waveform. I used [wavesurfer](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) to do so, but for each audio file it consume about 60-100 MB of memory and hence after playing a small set of them the browser crashes.

The [wavesurfer](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) uses **AudioContext** from [Web Audio](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/), so the question is how to use **AudioContext** for such long play lists? >10 audio files to be loaded one after one. If there're any alternative for **AudioContext** or [Web Audio](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/), what is it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no alternative for WebAudio, `AudioContext`.

You needed to design your workflow so that you are not crashing the browser with your JavaScript application. Consider only loading necessary resources and loading minimized version of resources which are not under active edit or lazily loading resources when needed then discarding after use.

If oyu try to load 100 audio files in any application you crash desktop and server because you simply run out of memory. In such scenarios naive approaches to handling data cannot be used.

If required preprocess the resources on the server-side for more compact format.

Comment: It was typo, they 10 audio files not 100

Comment: If you think you are not running out of memory please report this as an issue to your web browser authors. However 10 * 100 MB audio is one gigabyte which is more than normal large set for a 32-bit machine, so check memory usage with your operating system tools.

Comment: It is quite trivial to process the audio to smaller format and memory consumption so I suggest you research these kind of solutions.

Comment: It happens to my  customers as most of them are having 32-bit machines with 2 GB RAM, so they ran out of memory within 10 audio files, for my machine it works fine till 50-60 files

Comment: Keep your working set under the memory budget. Downsample audio for smaller memory consumption.

Comment: So, Now I used only 2 AudioContexts and I pre-load the next file only while the current one is working. Also I load the after next file in the AudioContext of the current one after it finished, and I still have the same problem. How can I free the memory of the finished file then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68412/discussion-between-phikry-and-mikko-ohtamaa).

Comment: The web audio API is intended to be used with exactly 1 AudioContext. You should try to refactor your code so that all tracks play from the same context. Wavesurfer lets you choose a pre-existing audioContext, instead of making a new one each time you need to play another file.

Also, how are you trying to release the memory? are you using the wavesurfer `destroy()` method when you're done playing a track?